# How many measurement samples does a typical phasor measurement unit (PMU) transmit in each communication session?

Tags: transmission-line, synchronous, phasor

Given a smart grid network, how many measurement samples (voltage and phase angles) does a typical PMU capture from a transmission line? 
I know that in each communication session, a PMU transmits roughly 200 to 300 bytes, but what are these bytes? Could a PMU (in practice) transmit less data? For instance, is it possible to transmit only 1 phase value and would this be useful for state estimation?

Answer (score 1):

The PMU samples power at the nominal frequency of **50 or 60** Hz and reports on current and voltage at a typical rate of **48** samples-per-cycle with **one** micro-second accuracy. The output of the PMU is a stream of time-tagged synchrophasors at a rate of up to **60** samples-per-second.
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/smart-grid-communication-enabled/9781118820247/OEBPS/9781118820247_epub_c_13.htm